# File not Found when compiling android resources (inconsistent across projects, consistent within projects)

Tags: android, windows, bazel

I have a project that uses bazel and includes a demo Android app to show some functionality and widgets.  I wanted to split this out as the base for a new demo/experimentation app to try out other widget combinations.  So I copied the `WORKSPACE` file and the code from the demo app package into a new project (the package names changed but I modified the code and `BUILD` files to account for this).  The original project builds just fine, but the new one consistently fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: D:/_bazel_out/s6wwoqrr/external/maven_android_everything/BUILD:568:11: Compiling Android resources for @maven_android_everything//:com
_google_android_material_material failed: (Exit 1): ResourceProcessorBusyBox.exe failed: error executing command bazel-out\x64_windows-opt-ex
ec-2B5CBBC6\bin\external\bazel_tools\src\tools\android\java\com\google\devtools\build\android\ResourceProcessorBusyBox.exe ... (remaining 1 a
rgument skipped)
Jul 29, 2022 3:04:29 PM java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef accept
SEVERE: Error during Compiling bazel-out\android-armeabi-v7a-fastbuild\bin\external\maven_android_everything\_aar\unzipped\resources\com_goog
le_android_material_material\res\animator\mtrl_extended_fab_change_size_collapse_motion_spec.xml:
Command: external\androidsdk\build-tools\33.0.0\aapt2.exe\
        compile\
        -v\
        --legacy\
        -o\
        C:\Users\bdlei\AppData\Local\Temp\android_resources_tmp3839340977225638696\compiled\bazel-out\android-armeabi-v7a-fastbuild\bin\exter
nal\maven_android_everything\_aar\unzipped\resources\com_google_android_material_material\res\
        bazel-out\android-armeabi-v7a-fastbuild\bin\external\maven_android_everything\_aar\unzipped\resources\com_google_android_material_mat
erial\res\animator\mtrl_extended_fab_change_size_collapse_motion_spec.xml
Output:
bazel-out\android-armeabi-v7a-fastbuild\bin\external\maven_android_everything\_aar\unzipped\resources\com_google_android_material_material\re
s\animator\mtrl_extended_fab_change_size_collapse_motion_spec.xml: error: file not found.

Exception in thread "main" com.google.devtools.build.android.aapt2.ResourceCompiler$CompileError
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.aapt2.ResourceCompiler$CompileError.of(ResourceCompiler.java:111)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.aapt2.ResourceCompiler$CompilingVisitor.getCompiledArtifacts(ResourceCompiler.java:431)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.aapt2.ResourceCompiler.getCompiledArtifacts(ResourceCompiler.java:465)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.UnvalidatedAndroidData.compile(UnvalidatedAndroidData.java:103)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.CompileLibraryResourcesAction.main(CompileLibraryResourcesAction.java:143)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox$Tool$6.call(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:99)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.processRequest(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:234)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.main(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:177)
        Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during Compiling bazel-out\android-armeabi-v7a-fastbuild\bin\external\maven_android_eve
rything\_aar\unzipped\resources\com_google_android_material_material\res\animator\mtrl_extended_fab_change_size_collapse_motion_spec.xml:    
Command: external\androidsdk\build-tools\33.0.0\aapt2.exe\
        compile\
        -v\
        --legacy\
        -o\
        C:\Users\bdlei\AppData\Local\Temp\android_resources_tmp3839340977225638696\compiled\bazel-out\android-armeabi-v7a-fastbuild\bin\exter
nal\maven_android_everything\_aar\unzipped\resources\com_google_android_material_material\res\
        bazel-out\android-armeabi-v7a-fastbuild\bin\external\maven_android_everything\_aar\unzipped\resources\com_google_android_material_mat
erial\res\animator\mtrl_extended_fab_change_size_collapse_motion_spec.xml
Output:
bazel-out\android-armeabi-v7a-fastbuild\bin\external\maven_android_everything\_aar\unzipped\resources\com_google_android_material_material\re
s\animator\mtrl_extended_fab_change_size_collapse_motion_spec.xml: error: file not found.

                at com.google.devtools.build.android.CommandHelper.execute(CommandHelper.java:42)
                at com.google.devtools.build.android.AaptCommandBuilder.execute(AaptCommandBuilder.java:297)
                at com.google.devtools.build.android.aapt2.ResourceCompiler$CompileTask.compile(ResourceCompiler.java:234)
                at com.google.devtools.build.android.aapt2.ResourceCompiler$CompileTask.call(ResourceCompiler.java:178)
                at com.google.devtools.build.android.aapt2.ResourceCompiler$CompileTask.call(ResourceCompiler.java:125)
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListe
nableFutureTask.java:125)
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
INFO: Elapsed time: 335.194s, Critical Path: 145.75s
INFO: 1568 processes: 74 internal, 1308 local, 186 worker.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

The referenced file: `bazel-out\android-armeabi-v7a-fastbuild\bin\external\maven_android_everything\_aar\unzipped\resources\com_google_android_material_mat erial\res\animator\mtrl_extended_fab_change_size_collapse_motion_spec.xml` *does exist* under the `bazel-out` directory of my project, but after the build failure, the temp directory `C:\Users\bdlei\AppData\Local\Temp\android_resources_tmp3839340977225638696` does not exist.  I had an explorer window open to my `AppData\Local\Temp` directory last time I tried building and many such `android_resources_temp...` came and went during the build (which I expected).  I removed older ones before trying the build again and while I wasn't able to track if the one named in the error ever existed, it does not exist afterwards (exactly one of these was left after the build failure).

The behavior is consistent: the original project consistently succeeds and the branched out fails.  This persists through `bazel clean`, `bazel sync`, and `bazel shutdown` calls.

Both projects are depending on android via a call into a 3rd "dependencies" project that creates a maven repo and builds a repo out of that:

```python
def android():
    if 'maven_android_everything' not in native.existing_rules():
        maven_install(
            name = "maven_android_everything",
            artifacts = [
                "androidx.activity:activity:1.2.3", # using 1.4.0 causes indexing issues in dex without force-jumbo, even without dagger-views.
                "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1",
                "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.3.1",
                "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1",
                "androidx.core:core:1.7.0",
                "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6",
                "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.3.1",
                "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0",
                "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0",
                "androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0",
                "com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0",
            ],
            excluded_artifacts = [
                maven.exclusion(
                    group = "com.google.guava",
                    artifact = "guava",
                ),
            ],
            repositories = [
                "https://maven.google.com",
                "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
            ],
        )

        new_simple_repo( # Simple custom repo rule to make an @android repo for use elsewhere
            name = "android",
            build_file_content = """
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

android_library(
    name = "android",
    exports = [
        "@guava//:concurrent",
        "@maven_android_everything//:androidx_activity_activity",
        "@maven_android_everything//:androidx_appcompat_appcompat",
        "@maven_android_everything//:androidx_appcompat_appcompat_resources",
        "@maven_android_everything//:androidx_constraintlayout_constraintlayout",
        "@maven_android_everything//:androidx_core_core",
        "@maven_android_everything//:androidx_fragment_fragment",
        "@maven_android_everything//:androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_viewmodel",
        "@maven_android_everything//:androidx_viewpager2_viewpager2",
        "@maven_android_everything//:androidx_recyclerview_recyclerview",
        "@maven_android_everything//:com_google_android_material_material",
    ],
)
""")
```

I've tried bumping versions to see if maybe that might help, but after slogging through dependency conflicts and finally getting `bazel sync` to succeed, I hit [this bug](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/13553).

I'm trying to pare my "playgroung" project down and see if I can isolate anything, but even removing a dependency on the original project doesn't help.

Comment: Oops, realized I left out some of the important info:
System: Windows 10
Bazel version 5.2.0 (via Bazelisk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some time to come back to this today and after much experimenting, including trying to set up a minimal example to use when filing a bug with `bazel`, I believe I found the problem.  It appears to relate to the lengths of resulting file names. By trying various lengths of the name of the maven repo used in the `maven_install` command, I was able to get the build to fail or pass consistently based on the length.  Any name 21 characters or shorter and the build succeeded, while any name longer than 21 characters would result in the file-not-found error.